# How do I display an image from a DataGridView to another PictureBox in a new Windows Form?

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview, crud

What I'm trying yo do is once I clicked on a row in my DataGridView, clicked on the view button, and it opens a new window that displays all the data from the DataGridView to the textboxes. I already did the first part, but I don't know how to do it with the images (I have 2 image columns). Can someone help me out? I'm only starting, sorry. This is my code for the view button that opens up another window. The picture boxes are always blank.

```
Private Sub btnView_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnView.Click

    If GunaDataGridView1.Rows.GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected) > 0 Then
        data.txtID.Text = GunaDataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString
        data.txtLN.Text = GunaDataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString
        data.txtFN.Text = GunaDataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString
        data.txtMN.Text = GunaDataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value.ToString
        data.txtGen.Text = GunaDataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value.ToString
        data.txtNum.Text = GunaDataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(5).Value.ToString
        data.txtDOB.Text = GunaDataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(6).Value.ToString
        data.txtAddress.Text = GunaDataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(7).Value.ToString
        data.txtPlate.Text = GunaDataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(8).Value.ToString
        data.txtVT.Text = GunaDataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(9).Value.ToString
        data.txtVB.Text = GunaDataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(10).Value.ToString
        data.txtVYM.Text = GunaDataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(11).Value.ToString
        data.txtSP.Text = GunaDataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(12).Value.ToString
        data.ownerPhoto.Image = GunaDataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(13).Value
        data.carPhoto.Image = GunaDataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(14).Value
        data.ShowDialog()

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: In my small tests, the posted code “appears” to work as expected. If the columns (13-14) in the grid are actual `DataGridViewImageColumns` then this code technically should work. In is unknown how you are defining the grids `DataSource` and we can only guess that columns 13 and 14 are `Image` columns. Try casting the cell `Value` to an `Image` object like…  `data.ownerPhoto.Image = CType(GunaDataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(13).Value, Image)`

Comment: In addition, It “appears” that your VB solution has the `Option strict` set to `Off`. It is recommended that you turn the `Option Strict` to `On` for your VB solutions. If it was “On” then you would get an error on the “image” lines of code complaining about it needs a cast to an `Image`. You need to keep in mind that the grids cell `Value` … `GunaDataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(13).Value` … is going to return an `Object` and this MAY be causing a problem however in my test it still worked with Options Strict set to `Off`. So I can only guess something else may be going on.

Comment: I keep getting this error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.Drawing.Image. 

It's the same error too after trying your code. :(

Comment: How is the code adding the image to the grid?

Comment: @JohnG I did it sir! I found another guy with the same problem and this comment was under all the rubble: 

  Dim bytes As Byte() = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(13).Value
        Using ms As New MemoryStream(bytes)
            PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
        End Using

Thank you for your help too, sir @JohnG!

Answer (score 0):

I saw another guy asked this question and another guy commented with this code line:

```
Dim bytes As Byte() = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(13).Value
    Using ms As New MemoryStream(bytes)
        ownerPP.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
    End Using

    Dim bit As Byte() = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(14).Value
    Using memory As New MemoryStream(bit)
        carPhoto.Image = Image.FromStream(memory)
    End Using
```

It works perfectly. I hope this helps someone out too.